# ASP.NET VB won't find item in sql database that IS THERE

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a page that has 3 text boxes. Of the first two, only one or the other is required to be filled out, or both. The third text box is a date and is required.

The issue is that if I fill in all of the fields:the first textbox(4 char integer), the second textbox(up to 9 char string) and the third textbox(date) and check the database using a stored procedure, it returns that it was found. Same goes if you only fill out the first and third textboxes. But if you fill out the second and third it refuses to return that it is found, even if I enter the exact information that is stored in the database.

The second textbox is for a school ID number that can vary from 4 characters to 9, depending on the schools ID system, and can contain letters as well as numbers. Something about that is causing an issue.

Here is my code for textbox 2:

```
<tr>
<td>Enter Student ID at Institution</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="textSID" runat="server" MaxLength="9" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my VB back for textbox 2:

```
Protected Sub btn_Cont_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Cont.Click
    Dim StudentIDLast4 As Integer = Val(textSSN.Text)
    Dim StudentIDInst As String = textSID.Text.ToUpper
    Dim DateOfBirth As String = textDOB.Text
    Dim IPaddress As String = Request.UserHostAddress()

    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim returnValue As String
    Dim returnCount As Integer

    cmd.CommandText = "proc_ReverseTransferConsent_Find_Match"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDLast4", StudentIDLast4)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDInst", StudentIDInst)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPaddress", IPaddress)

    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    If Page.IsValid Then
        sqlConnection1.Open()
        returnValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        sqlConnection1.Close()
        returnCount = returnValue.Length
        If returnCount > 4 Then
            Response.Redirect("RTAgreement.aspx?rVal=" + returnValue)
            Label1.Text = returnCount
            Label2.Text = returnValue
        Else
            Label2.Text = StudentIDInst
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the sql script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_ReverseTransferConsent_Find_Match]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StudentIDLast4 VARCHAR(4),
@StudentIDInst VARCHAR(9),
@DateOfBirth DATETIME,
@IPaddress VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Results UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @Results = Null

INSERT INTO ReverseTransferConsent_Attempt
    ([StudentIdentificationNumber],
    [StudentIdentificationNumberInst],
    [DateOfBirth],
    [IPaddress],
    [CreatedDate])
VALUES
    (@StudentIDLast4,
    @StudentIDInst,
    @DateOfBirth,
    @IPaddress,
    GETDATE())      


IF @StudentIDLast4 <> '' And @StudentIDInst <> '' And @DateOfBirth Is Not Null
    SELECT @Results = Case When ConsentAuthCode Is Not Null Then ConsentAuthCode Else Null End
    FROM ReverseTransferConsent
    WHERE RIGHT(StudentIdentificationNumber,4) = @StudentIDLast4
        And StudentIdentificationNumberInst = @StudentIDInst
        And DateOfBirthConverted = @DateOfBirth

ELSE IF @StudentIDLast4 <> '' And @DateOfBirth Is Not Null

    SELECT @Results = Case When ConsentAuthCode Is Not Null Then ConsentAuthCode Else Null End
    FROM ReverseTransferConsent
    WHERE RIGHT(StudentIdentificationNumber,4) = @StudentIDLast4
        And DateOfBirthConverted = @DateOfBirth

ELSE IF @StudentIDInst <> '' And @DateOfBirth Is Not Null

    SELECT @Results = Case When ConsentAuthCode Is Not Null Then ConsentAuthCode Else Null End
    FROM ReverseTransferConsent
    WHERE StudentIdentificationNumberInst = @StudentIDInst
        And DateOfBirthConverted = @DateOfBirth

SELECT @Results As Result
```

This is all the code pertinent to textbox 2. The value I type into the textbox, for example S02394, is converted to uppercase and stored and sent to the procedure and stored into @StudentIDInst VARCHAR(9) where it is passed through the procedure and checked with the database column(StudentIdentificationNumberInst). Even though it could be an exact match to what is in the database it is always coming back null and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Since you're never setting `@DateOfBirth` and if it's not set you skip over the `SELECT`, I don't see how that code could ever do anything.

Comment: I just edited it to include all of the VB back and the entire sql procedure.

Comment: I just tried this and still no luck: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentIDInst", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9).Value = StudentIDInst` I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now. Why won't my string check itself with the string in the database when they are the exact same?

Comment: Royale (great nick, BTW) I see nothing obviously wrong with your code, but I do not have your database, web server, nor the values you are testing, but I would target your efforts on your third `SELECT` with `WHERE StudentIdentificationNumberInst ...`. Are you sure this is being run? Try removing the `IF @StudentIDInst <> ...` or returning a diagnostic value in the query.